# Tweepy throws an error for no apparent reason

Tags: python, tweepy

I was trying to make a simple Twitter bot and it threw a 401 error without much info. Here's the code and the error:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "..."

consumer_secret = "..."

key = "..."

secret = "..."

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status('Hello World')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/roeyd/twitterbot/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    api.update_status('Hello World')
  File "C:\Dev\twitterbot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dev\twitterbot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 1121, in update_status
    return self.request(
  File "C:\Dev\twitterbot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 257, in request
    raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
```

I really hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: You are not providing valid key/ secret token. Or your key do not have access. Double check that

Comment: Try explicitly defining "status" as in: api.update_status(status='Hello World').

Comment: I tested code with my keys and it works for me - if I try to use wrong keys then I get different errors. I never get `401`. But maybe it needs special settings in https://developer.twitter.com/

Comment: maybe you should digg in source code of `api.py` (which you see in error message) and add `print()` to see what values makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're providing the right credentials and that you've given your app the write permission.

See [the FAQ section in Tweepy's documentation about this](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error).